# how to send an array of integers and chars with Paho MQTT C Client

Tags: c, mqtt

I am new to MQTT. my final project is to send an array that contains a UNIX-based timestamp and its timezone code and a few integer values.

following Paho MQTT C Client - MQTT Client Library Encyclopedia, I come up with its code snippet:

```
#include "stdio.h"
#include "stdlib.h"
#include "string.h"
#include "MQTTClient.h"

#define ADDRESS     "tcp://localhost:1883"
#define CLIENTID    "ExampleClientPub"
#define TOPIC       "testTopic"
#define PAYLOAD     "220"
#define QOS         0
#define TIMEOUT     10000L

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    MQTTClient client;
    MQTTClient_connectOptions conn_opts = MQTTClient_connectOptions_initializer;
    MQTTClient_message pubmsg = MQTTClient_message_initializer;
    MQTTClient_deliveryToken token;
    int rc;

    MQTTClient_create(&client, ADDRESS, CLIENTID,
        MQTTCLIENT_PERSISTENCE_NONE, NULL);
    conn_opts.keepAliveInterval = 20;
    conn_opts.cleansession = 1;

    if ((rc = MQTTClient_connect(client, &conn_opts)) != MQTTCLIENT_SUCCESS)
    {
        printf("Failed to connect, return code %d\n", rc);
        exit(-1);
    }
    int arr [3] = {1, 2, 3};
    pubmsg.payload = arr; // PAYLOAD;
    pubmsg.payloadlen = strlen(PAYLOAD);
    pubmsg.qos = QOS;
    pubmsg.retained = 0;

    // while(1){
            
        MQTTClient_publishMessage(client, TOPIC, &pubmsg, &token);
    // }

    printf("Waiting for up to %d seconds for publication of %s\n"
            "on topic %s for client with ClientID: %s\n",
            (int)(TIMEOUT/1000), PAYLOAD, TOPIC, CLIENTID);
    rc = MQTTClient_waitForCompletion(client, token, TIMEOUT);
    printf("Message with delivery token %d delivered\n", token);
    MQTTClient_disconnect(client, 10000);
    MQTTClient_destroy(&client);
    return rc;
}
```

I changed its payload with an array (for example with only int values). but when I publish the msg, I get an undefined character on the subscriber side:

```
testClient1@localhost> sub -t testTopic -s
"
```

can someone please tell me how can I send that array?

Answer (score 0):

`strlen(payload)` won't work because `arr` is not a null terminated string.

The payload size should be `sizeof arr / sizeof int` (assuming it might change in length later)

But even after that you WILL get what looks like garbage out of the mosquitto_sub command because by default to treats all payloads as strings and you haven't sent a string, you've sent 3 int values that do not map to printable characters.

You need to look at the `OUTPUT FORMAT` section of the mosquitto_sub man page [here](https://mosquitto.org/man/mosquitto_sub-1.html#outputformat)

Comment: So, does it mean I should take care of formatting on the subscriber side? I changed payload size already.

Comment: If you expect to see something meaningful then yes.

Comment: can you please provide a sample code? I don't know where to begin

Comment: No, Stack Overflow doesn't work that day. Also you haven't included any of the subscription code or explained what you are actually trying to achieve